# Memory Usage of the c directory files in cmd

Tags: cmd

So, im running dir c:\ in command prompt and it shows me,

dir c:\
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is BE7A-83CF

Directory of c:\

12/06/2012  04:48 PM              Accumedic

02/10/2016  10:27 AM           221,431 avgremover.log

12/23/2015  01:44 AM             3,072 Datacollectors.db

05/08/2012  05:45 PM              DELL

02/18/2011  11:46 AM              Drivers

02/02/2012  02:17 PM            23,760 FLBS1601.TEST

02/02/2012  02:29 PM            23,760 FLBS1602.TEST

02/18/2011  11:46 AM              Install

02/06/2012  11:48 AM                22 Network.bat

07/13/2009  11:20 PM              PerfLogs

02/01/2016  03:27 PM              Program Files

10/14/2015  03:05 PM              Program Files (x86)

12/27/2011  01:34 PM              Projects

05/04/2016  08:52 AM              SQL_Docs

04/07/2014  04:30 PM              temp

07/23/2015  11:19 AM              Users

05/04/2016  08:47 AM              Windows

```
           5 File(s)        272,045 bytes
          12 Dir(s)   1,979,822,080 bytes free
```

Is there a command to see the disk usage of each of the files, instead of just the total? Preferably, in a similar format, and not individually looking each one up.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing you the sizes of the files in the directory. From your question:

```
02/10/2016 10:27 AM 221,431 avgremover.log
12/23/2015 01:44 AM 3,072 Datacollectors.db
```

This is telling you that `avgremover.log` is 221,431 bytes in size. Most of the lines in your example don't have a number because they are directories. `dir` doesn't list a size for them.

Comment: "Most of the lines in your example don't have a number because they are directories. dir doesn't list a size for them." Is there a way to get it to show them. That is my issue, i want to see the disk usage of the files in a certain directory.

Comment: @internstrick So you want the directory entries to show the total number of bytes taken up by all the files under that directory? The `dir` command cannot do that. You can use the `/s` switch to display all the files under the directory with each file's size, but there's not a switch to add this all up. One reason is that this could take considerable time to compute.